# Combing LEFT and LEN functions

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write code to organize a data dump. 
Basically I need to extract 
asdf from: *123456**asdf**123456789*

I can do this in normal worksheet mode in Excel, but I am having trouble with this in VBA. Theoretically the code below should return the string 9 spaces left and 9 spaces right, but the code just hangs there with an error.

```
Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
LastRow = wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For MyRow = 1 To LastRow
    celltxt = wks.Cells(MyRow, 1).Text
    If InStr(1, celltxt, "name") Then
        LString = Len(wks.Cells(MyRow, 1))
        wks.Cells(MyRow, 1) = RIGHT(LEFT(wks.Cells(MyRow, 1),LString-6),LString -9)
    End If
Next For
```

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. To actually get ***asdf*** from your example string it should be: `RIGHT(LEFT(celltxt,LEN(celltxt)-9),LEN(celltxt)-15)` or you can use `MID(celltxt,7,4)`. Did I miss something from your post?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, figured it out. I already have the variable celltxt defined, so I can just refer to that for the `LEN` function. It must have been an error because of the way I was trying to reference the cell I'm editing.

```
If InStr(1, celltxt, "name") Then
    wks.Cells(MyRow, 1) = Right(Left(celltxt, Len(celltxt) - 7), Len(celltxt) - 16)
End If
```

Comment: If you are using `Left` and then `Right` like this, would it make more sense to use `Mid(celltxt, 10, Len(celltxt) - 16)` instead?  (starts at character 10, and ignores the last 7 characters)

Comment: I didn't know about Mid, but it wouldn't work well with what I am doing because the string I want to extract is varying lengths while the string I want to truncate has fixed length

Comment: the `Mid` code I posted is functionally identical to your `Right(Left(..)..)` code, because `Right("ABCD",2)` is the same as `Mid("ABCD", 3, 2)` and `Left("ABCDEF",4)` is the same as `Mid("ABCDED",1,4)`  All you need is to know your Start position and either End Position (`Mid(String, Start, 1 + End - Start)`) or Length (`Mid(String, Start, Length)`)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to simply replace the string portion with nothing?

```
For MyRow = 1 To LastRow
     wks.Cells(MyRow, 1) = replace(wks.Cells(MyRow, 1), "name", vbnullstring, vbtextcompare)
Next For
```